# Building a .net core restful api and I need to return a byte array of an image in the response. The image first needs to be converted from html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, pdfsharp

I am working in Visual Studio 2019 with a .net core restful app that returns a byte array of an image to be printed. I have html templates stored that need to be converted to an image so I'm using PdfSharpCore, mostly because that's the best I could find without having to purchase a library. My problem is the sample of code that I found says that it works for PdfSharpCore, but it uses XImage.FromGdiPlusImage in the sample which is not available in PdfSharpCore only in PdfSharp which is supposedly not supported in an .net core app.  I've been at this all day trying to get it to compile.  Any help would be appreciated. If I'm way off base and there is an easier way to achieve this feel free to share.

```
public byte[] GetBitmapByteArrayFromHtmlString( String html )
{
    byte[]    data;

    // Convert the HTML string to a PDF document
    //HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

    // Create an XGraphics object from the first page of the PDF document
    PdfDocument doc = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html,PdfSharpCore.PageSize.A0,20,null,null,null);
    PdfPage page = doc.Pages[0];
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage( doc.Pages[0] );

    // Create an XImage object from the XGraphics object
    int width = Convert.ToInt32(gfx.PdfPage.Width.ToString());
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(gfx.PdfPage.Height.ToString());
    XImage image = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(new Bitmap(width, height));

    // Create a bitmap image from the XImage object
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap( image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb );
    bitmap.SetResolution( (float) image.HorizontalResolution, (float) image.VerticalResolution );

    using( MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream() )
    {
        bitmap.Save( stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png );
        data = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return data;
   
    // Save the bitmap image to a file
    //bitmap.Save("image.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

} /* End GetBitmapByteArrayFromHtmlString */
```

Comment: In the code snippet, no content is added to the `Bitmap` and the variable `image` is not used anywhere. Unclear what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `XImage.FromGdiPlusImage` then one solution is this:

1. Save the `Bitmap` to a `MemoryStream` (in a format supported by the Core build of PDFsharp)
2. Create an `XImage` from that `MemoryStream`

OTOH, if your code uses the `Bitmap` class from GDI+, then consider using the GDI build of PDFsharp that supports `XImage.FromGdiPlusImage`. But, as you wrote, this is not available in Core environments under Linux or Mac.